# How can I convert this to a single line comprehension for combinations?

Tags: python

I've done this to list all the permutations of rolling two dice, but I need to convert it to a single line comprehension of all the *combinations* and I am struggling.

```
from itertools import product

myList = list(product(range(1,7), repeat=2)) 


print myList
```

Comment: are you looking for `[(i,j) for i in range(1,7) for j in range(1,7)]`?

Comment: Why? What you have is already faster and more readable

Comment: Can you write it as a *regular* for loop, not a comprehension?

Answer (score 0):

Itertools also has a function for combinations that allow repeating elements:

```
import itertools
c = list(iter.combinations_with_replacement(range(1,7),2))

[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 5), (5, 6), (6, 6)]
```